# SFMC Connector 'test/seed' Contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact, marketing-cloud-connect

When the Connector is installed, so all Contacts are brought in through Synchronized Data Extensions...

What is the best way to configure 'test/seed' records?

1. Would you create 'dummy' records in CRM that would then get synced over?
2. Do you create a Standard DE to mirror the Sync DE? What if the sync DE is over 100 fields?
3. ???

Answer (score 0):

We had to sync with an existing Contact object which had more than a million record, we added a checkbox field in service cloud for the Contact Object ,IsSyncRequired which we used as a boolean field, while syncing the records in marketing cloud we synced  records which only had that boolean value true,That way we managed the no of records that would be synced as we didn't want all the contacts coming to Marketing Cloud.

We also created a small seed data of 15-20 records in csv format with the boolean IsSyncRequired=TRUE and used data loader to load it into service cloud.If we needed to delete the record we would delete records only with this flag set as TRUE and the records would automatically be removed from Marketing Cloud .
If the Sync DE needs to be used in Journey Builder,You have to create a Standard DE,we used query under Automation Studio to create the same .